# What does $k^*/k^{*^2}$ mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation, field-theory

I'm trying to get a more concrete understanding of what these elements 'look like.'

---

Here $k$ is a field, $k^*$ is multiplicative  group, and $(k^*)^2$ consists of the squares in $k^*$.

Comment: Where did you see this notation? $\;$

Comment: A Course in Arithmetic by Jean-Pierre Serre (on page 35 for example)

Comment: Is it just the square-free elements of k?

Comment: It's just the quotient of two abelian groups. What exactly do you mean by 'looks like'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, $k$ is a field. In this case, $k^*$ is its multiplicative groups and $k^{*^2}$ is the subgroup of squares.

What the quotient group $k^*/k^{*^2}$ looks like depends very much on $k$.

For $k=\mathbb C$, $\quad k^*/k^{*^2}$ is the trivial group.

For $k=\mathbb R$, $\quad k^*/k^{*^2}$ is the cyclic group of order $2$.

For $k=\mathbb Q$, $\quad k^*/k^{*^2}$ can be described by the square-free fractions, and so is the set of all finite products of primes to the power $\pm1$, but I don't know which concrete group it is.

Comment: Your last group is the direct product of countable copies of groups of order 2, so it is concrete enough.

Comment: @PVanchinathan, right, thanks! But it's the infinite direct *sum*, not *product* (using Wikipedia's terminology) because all but finitely many components are $1$.